# Conversion failed when converting date and / or time from character string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I was trying to create a procedure as follows :

```
CREATE PROC prc_invoice_add
AS
BEGIN
insert into INVOICE
(INV_NUMBER,CUS_CODE,INV_DATE)
VALUES (8006,1000,cast('30-APRL-08 00:00:00 AM ' as DATETIME2))
END
```

But whenever I execute this procedure this error message pops up :

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in **Aprl**

Pass it as **April** or **Apr**

try this

```
CREATE PROC prc_invoice_add
AS
BEGIN
insert into INVOICE
(INV_NUMBER,CUS_CODE,INV_DATE)
VALUES (8006,1000,cast('30-APRIL-08 00:00:00 AM ' as DATETIME2))
END
```

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
CREATE PROC prc_invoice_add
AS
BEGIN
insert into INVOICE
(INV_NUMBER,CUS_CODE,INV_DATE)
VALUES (8006,1000,cast('30-APR-08 00:00:00 AM ' as DATETIME2))
END
```

your format of date is dd-MMM-yyyy, in this format APRIL is writtan as apr.

Answer (score 0):

Use convert, Specifically to cast date time.

```
CONVERT(DATETIME2,'30-APR-08 00:00:00 AM',113)
```